# How to insert a specific text at the end of exisitng data in a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014. Assume I have a table called `T1` with 2 columns, `IdNumber` and `Notes`. Table `T1` contains around 300,000 records.

The `Notes` column is a free text column, meaning users have entered therein free text. Some records have this column empty (no text entered).

I now have a list of `IdNumbers` where I need to add this specific text "(TOC)" in the Notes column of `T1`, ideally at the end of any text already present therein. I have created a table called `tempID` which contains the list of all these IdNumbers.

Here is how table `T1` looks (extract):

```
IdNumber        Notes
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   101          Guest does not like beer
   154          wedding anniversary - to prepare a cake - 03052020
   160
```

`IdNumber = 160` has a blank/empty `Notes` column.

Here is what I want to achieve (assuming "(TOC)" need to be added to these 3 IdNumbers):

```
IdNumber        Notes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  101           Guest does not like beer (TOC)
  154           wedding anniversary - to prepare a cake - 03052020 (TOC)
  160           (TOC)
```

How can I do this (I have a list of around 1500 IdNumbers)?

This is where I am stuck with my SQL query:

```
UPDATE T1
INSERT INTO [Notes]
VALUE ('(TOC)') ----stuck here!
WHERE [IdNumber] in (Select [IdNumber] from [tempID]
```

I think it should be done differently since my above query will simply overwrite the existing content of the `Notes` column with "(TOC)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just simply add `(TOC)` to your column - and make sure to be aware that if `Notes` is `NULL`, you need to do some extra handling:

```
UPDATE dbo.T1
SET Notes = ISNUL(Notes, '') + ' (TOC)'
WHERE IdNumber IN (SELECT IdNumber FROM dbo.tempID);
```

With the `ISNULL()` operator, you turn a `NULL` into an empty string, which can then be concatenated with the `(TOC)` string. If you omit this, then it wouldn't work, because concatenating `NULL` with anything else will still results in `NULL`

Comment: @user3115933 . . . This leaves a space before `(TOC)` when `notes` is `NULL`.  Hence, I don't think it fully answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `concat()` does exactly what you want -- ignoring `NULL` values:

```
UPDATE dbo.T1
    SET Notes = CONCAT(Notes, ' (TOC)')
    WHERE IdNumber IN (SELECT t.IdNumber FROM dbo.tempID t);
```

The only caveat is that you seem to want `ltrim()` to remove the leading space when `notes` is `NULL`:

```
UPDATE dbo.T1
    SET Notes = LTRIM(CONCAT(Notes, ' (TOC)'))
    WHERE IdNumber IN (SELECT t.IdNumber FROM dbo.tempID t);
```

This will remove the leading space for `NULL` values -- and any leading `NULL`s in `notes`.

You can do this with `COALESCE()` and `+` as well:

```
UPDATE dbo.T1
    SET Notes = COALESCE(Notes + ' ', '') + '(TOC)'
    WHERE IdNumber IN (SELECT t.IdNumber FROM dbo.tempID t);
```

Comment: Hmmm. Your second query might remove some already existing intentional leading spaces as well. I would settle with your third (and last) query or consider using a CASE statement to check for NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Notes = ISNULL(T1.Notes + ' ', '') + '(TOC)'
from T1 inner join dbo.tempID T2 on T1.IdNumber=T2.IdNumber
```